# Как передать переменную от клиента (JavaScript) к серверу (Node,js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

допустим есть на сайте кнопка, нажимая которую переменная,сформированная на стороне клиента, отправлялась бы на сервер и там принималась для дальнейших манипуляций
Клиентская часть написана на javascript, а сервер на node.js

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `XHR` или `fetch` на клиенте, а на сервере добавьте обработчик для запросов по соответствующим путям. Мы в вас верим

Comment: Спасибо, попробую